# Drop down under MS Azure 'Host in the cloud' check box doesn't has 'App Service' value

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I am trying to create new Web application in cloud from MS visual studio 2015, I am not able to find  'App Service' value in the drop down under MS Azure 'Host in the cloud' check box. I am able to find 'Web App'. I continued to create application by selecting 'Web App' in the drop down. But when publishing my application, in the select target section I am not seeing my web app which I created under azure portal. Please help and share your views.

Comment: If there is more information about the version of your VS, Azure SDK and screenshot of the publish interface will be more helpful. Also make sure that you select the corrosponding subscription.

Comment: Hi @TomSun, I am using VS2015, azure SDK V2.0.

Comment: Please have a try to update the Azure SDK from 2.0 to 2.9.6. In Visual Studio go to Tools >> Extensions and Updates. Click on  Updates in the left-hand pane. You should see the Azure SDK with a  Update button. And try it again.